# Django add link after slice

Tags: django, templates, href, slice

i have the following in my html template:

```
<h1><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h1>
<p>{{ post.content|slice:":1000"|linebreaksbr }}</p>
```

i want that after the slice to 1000 chars a href to the full article gets displayd.
e.g.:

```
<h1><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h1>
<p>{{ post.content|slice:":1000"|link:"... read on" href= url 'post_detail'|linebreaksbr }}</p>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well separate the text of the partial article from the link. Like:

```
<p>{{ post.content|slice:":1000"|linebreaksbr}}
  <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">read on</a></p>
```

Typically by splitting up problems in subproblems, the problem becomes easier to manage.

The `{% url ... %}` is probably with `pk=post.pk` or something similar, since otherwise it would link to the `post_details`, but without a specific post.

Alternatively, if you only want to show `read on` when the content is sliced, you can use an `{% if ... %}`:

```
<p>{{ post.content|slice:":1000"|linebreaksbr}}
  {% if post.content|length > 1000 %}
  <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">read on</a>
  {% endif %}</p>
```